# What kind of powershell syntax is this?

Tags: powershell, syntax, calculated-property

Im working on a powershell file and im a bit confused because of the following syntax:
[image]

what kind of syntax is this??? And where can I read more about it?
Is "select" just an abbrevation for select-object?

Comment: You'll want to read [`about_Calculated_Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: To add to Mathias' comment: the arguments being passed to `select` (in the form of `@{ key = value; ... }`) are _special-purpose_ [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) with _prescribed entries_ that provide the implementation of calculated properties.